# Convergence of power series cannot contain pole

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

The following is the question:

> The function $1/\sin z$ is expressed as a power series around the point $z_0 = 4i + \pi/2$. Explain why the radius of convergence cannot exceed $R = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{64 + \pi^2}$.

---

My attempt:
The distance of $0$ from $z_0$ is $R$. Thus, if the radius of convergence exceeded $R$, then $0$ would be within the disc of convergence. The function $1/\sin z$ blows up as $z\to 0$ and thus, this would pose a problem.
However, there is the following possibility that I would like to exclude:

> The power series agrees with $1/\sin z$ on some disc of $r < R$ around $z_0$ but still converges on a disc of radius $R' > R$ without agreeing with $1/\sin z$ outside the disc of radius $r$.

---

Now, by using something such as the Identity theorem, it is clear that the above possibility cannot happen. However, I came across notes where this exercise was given at a more elementary level. (Just after the introduction of power series.) Thus, I'm looking for a more elementary solution.

---

**EDIT:** To further clarify what I meant-
I wish to show that the following is not possible:

> There exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ of complex numbers and $r > 0$ such that:
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)^n = \dfrac{1}{\sin z}$$
>   for all $|z - z_0| < r$.
>   Furthermore, the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_n(z - z_0)^n$ is greater than $R$.

Comment: What is the meaning of "the function $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ is expressed as a power series" if not "the power series converges to $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ in the disc of convergence"?

Comment: That there exists some $r > 0$ such that the power series and $1/\sin z$ agree on the disc of radius $r$ centred at $z_0$. Now, it is could also be possible (I precisely wish to show that it's not) that the power series does converge on a bigger disc without agreeing with $1/\sin z$.

Comment: To be more explicit mathematically, I have added an edit. Hopefully, that clarifies it.

Comment: Is it fine to use the fact that for every function $f$ holomorphic in a region $D$ and every $p \in D$, $f$ equals some power series around $p$ in the maximal open disc centered at $p$ contained in $D$?

Comment: @Adayah: nope, even that comes later.

Comment: Then I suppose such an elementary proof does not exist. But maybe in the notes you mentioned the phrase "$\frac{1}{\sin z}$ is expressed as a power series" could after all mean what I suggested in the first comment?

Comment: I asked the professor and he did intend on using the fact that the power series agrees with the function on the maximal open disc. Using that, I can solve it. However, you may add it as an answer and I'll approve it for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer myself. The idea is to use the following fact:

> Let $f:\Omega \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic and let $z_0 \in \Omega$. Then, $f$ admits a power series representation centred at $z_0$. Moreover, this power series agrees with $f$ on the maximal open disc $D \subset \Omega$ centred at $z_0$.

We proceed as follows:
Define $f(z) := 1/\sin z$ for $z \in \Bbb C\setminus\{n\pi \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$.
Let $D = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid |z - z_0| < R\}$. ($z_0$ and $R$ being as in the question.)
It is clear that $D$ is the maximal disc as mentioned in the fact.

---

Suppose that the power series converged on a strictly larger disc $D'$.
Let $P:D'\to\Bbb C$ denote the function defined by the power series. Also, note that $P$ is continuous.
We have $P|_D = f|_D$. (By the fact.)

Then, $0 \in {\rm int}\ D'$ and thus, the power series converges (absolutely) at $0$.
Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence in $D$ such that $z_n \to 0$. (Such a sequence exists as $0 \in \bar{D}$.)
Since $P$ is continuous, we must have
$$P(z_n) \to P(0).$$
On the other hand, we have $P(z_n) = f(z_n)$ and thus,
$$P(z_n) = f(z_n) = \dfrac{1}{\sin z_n},$$
which diverges since $z_n \to 0$.

The above is a contradiction.